# I want to sum the rows of a column in multiindex-dataframe but keep the values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have dataframe of the form:

```
                                   Price  Quantity
Date       Mat        Str    Type                 
2016-01-05 2016-02-19 3125.0 C        44     0.069
                             C        44     0.032
                             C        44     0.015
2016-01-06 2016-02-15 3169.0 P        69     0.069
```

I wish to sum the rows of the column *Quantity* but keep the Price column intact (make an other price column with the mean for example)

I thought about making the *Price* column a part of the index, but as my objective is to compare the *Price* and *Quantity* of this Df with an other Df of similar shape I might run into some problems.

Here's some code to recreate the df:

```py
import pandas as pd



data = [{'Date':'2016-01-05', 'Mat':'2016-02-19', 'Str': 3125.0, 'Type': 'C', 'Quantity':0.069, 'Price':44},
        {'Date':'2016-01-05', 'Mat':'2016-02-19', 'Str': 3125.0, 'Type': 'C', 'Quantity':0.032, 'Price':44},
        {'Date':'2016-01-05', 'Mat':'2016-02-19', 'Str': 3125.0, 'Type': 'C', 'Quantity':0.015, 'Price':44},
        {'Date':'2016-01-06', 'Mat':'2016-02-15', 'Str': 3169.0, 'Type': 'P', 'Quantity':0.069, 'Price':69}]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df1.set_index(['Date', 'Mat', 'Str', 'Type'])
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need grouping by some level(s) - e.g. by first by `level=0` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for filling new column by aggregate values:

```
df1['Sum'] = df1.groupby(level=0)['Quantity'].transform('sum')
print (df1)
                                   Quantity  Price    Sum
Date       Mat        Str    Type                        
2016-01-05 2016-02-19 3125.0 C        0.069     44  0.116
                             C        0.032     44  0.116
                             C        0.015     44  0.116
2016-01-06 2016-02-15 3169.0 P        0.069     69  0.069
```

Comment: @meowcatz42 - Super, so expected output is new column like in my answer?

Comment: Yes, it's better than what I wanted at first since simply summing the rows in the same column will make me lose some information that I need for future comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df1.groupby(['Date','Str','Mat','Type']).agg( Q_sum=('Quantity', 'sum'), Price=('Price','mean')).reset_index()
```

Result is as below

```
Date    Str     Mat     Type    Q_sum   Price
2016-01-05  3125.0  2016-02-19  C   0.116   44
2016-01-06  3169.0  2016-02-15  P   0.069   69
```

[image]

Comment: It says that the agg() is missing one required positional argument

Comment: it is working for me perfectly. please copy it exactly as it is.

Comment: Thanks, dude! I want to upvote you but I can't for the moment.

Comment: @mohanys - You can upvote question for 15 points, so OP can upvote. ;)

Comment: @mohanys - I have more upvotes of question, reason is I remember how hard is get some points if start in SO ;) So if question is not extra problematic, I always upvote... ;)